# Convert a nested Dictionary to a nested List with List Comprehension method in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to convert the following nested dictionary into a nested list of lists with List Comprehension method for better performance:

```
n = {
"ETHBTC": {
    "2021-09-04 01:55:00": {
        "open": 0.078998,
        "close": 0.079007,
        "volume": 44.952200000000005
    },
     "2021-09-04 01:56:00": {
        "open": 0.079005,
        "close": 0.078959,
        "volume": 68.62790000000001
    },
    "2021-09-04 01:57:01": {
        "open": 0.07896,
        "close": 0.078962,
        "volume": 131.6615000000001
    },
    "2021-09-04 01:58:00": {
        "open": 0.078966,
        "close": 0.078988,
        "volume": 157.38520000000005
    }
}
   "BTCUSDT": {
    "2021-09-04 01:55:00": {
        "open": 49730.55,
        "close": 49710.01,
        "volume": 28.57857999999999
    },
    "2021-09-04 01:56:00": {
        "open": 49710.0,
        "close": 49681.35,
        "volume": 19.088980000000017
    },
    "2021-09-04 01:57:00": {
        "open": 49681.36,
        "close": 49737.05,
        "volume": 20.885500000000008
    },
    "2021-09-04 01:58:00": {
        "open": 49737.06,
        "close": 49757.33,
        "volume": 35.782369999999965
    }
}
```

Expected output to be with let say with the "close" value i am trying to do this in one liner code for better efficiency:

```
result = ["ETHBTC"[0.079007, 0.078959, 0.078962, 0.078988],
          "BTCUSDT"[49710.01, 49681.35, 49737.05, 49757.33]]
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried already? Also, what do you mean by efficiency? A one liner isn't always the most efficient, either for performance or for readability.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? I don't see why you cant use just the dictionary

Comment: By efficiency i mean better performance. In my understanding List comprehension is better than a for loop. And i want to calculate moving average after converting it to a list .

Comment: @ScrappyCoco Yes, but actually no. It honestly depends and if you're asking this type of question then you need to reconsider either your techniques in python or your data model. Don't worry about efficiency in python until after you have a functioning product. And if you want efficiency to this scale then python may not the language of choice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just because there's less code on the screen doesn't mean it's more efficient.** Along with that, if transforming data down means losing meaningful data then it is superfluous to the grand scheme. Also python is not about starting with efficiency but with functionality. After that you can revisit and improve upon bottlenecks/etc...

That said I can see the need to do this, and yes probably one of the most efficient and readable ways to do this would be a one line snippet of code. Please refer to [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) as it works out that it refers to what I just said.

**But why a list?** Isn't a hash table/lookup more efficient than a list of unique key'd dict's?

---

Finally I leave you with what is, my mind, the correct way to implement your expected output. But consider my thoughts above.

```
>>> {k: [d['close'] for d in v.values()] for k, v in n.items()}
{"ETHBTC": [0.079007, 0.078959, 0.078962, 0.078988],
 "BTCUSDT": [49710.01, 49681.35, 49737.05, 49757.33]}
```

If you must have a list of dict's you can easily modify the above code to achieve the desired result:

```
>>> [{k: [d['close'] for d in v.values()]} for k, v in n.items()]
[{"ETHBTC": [0.079007, 0.078959, 0.078962, 0.078988]},
 {"BTCUSDT": [49710.01, 49681.35, 49737.05, 49757.33]}]
```

**FYI**: *Before asking someone especially this site a question it should behoove you to attempt to find the answer yourself or attempt to find it.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using this code with my algo trade setup. my function need a list to calculate moving averages for which i need to convert it to a list. I understand python is slow but i have no other choice. currently my function uses numba do you have any other suggestion for speed up.

Comment: using numpy/numba/pandas/dask/... would be a start. They take the hard work away from python and rely on c or other more performant languages to perform the heavy lifting for you.